# How to select highest relative value of column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, conditional-statements

I want to select the row which has highest value in column "price" of the ones fullfilling the condition.

Using MAX() like shown below doesn't work for me since it's cehcking the highest absolute value of that column.

```
"SELECT * FROM parts_list WHERE " . (implode(' = 1 AND ', $utilization)) . " = 1 AND (part_price = (SELECT MAX(part_price) FROM parts_list))"
```

I only want it to select the one with the highest value for 'part_price' of the ones which fullfill:

```
 . (implode(' = 1 AND ', $utilization)) . " = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first `ORDER BY part_price DESC` and then use `TOP 1` to only get the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Just 2 minutes after I posted I had an idea:

```
"SELECT MAX(part_price) * FROM parts_list WHERE " . (implode(' = 1 AND ', $utilization)) . " = 1 AND (part_price = (SELECT MAX(part_price) FROM parts_list WHERE ".implode(' = 1 AND ', $utilization)." = 1))");
```